# Follow up - Google Script to Fill out HTML Form

Tags: html, forms, web, automation

I tried commenting on the response by Rob in the original post:
[Google Script to Fill out HTML Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60085584/google-script-to-fill-out-html-form)

But I am shy of 11 points to do so, hence asking my own question here.
I have a similar web form automation requirement and I like Rob's response on using

> UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)

I like this approach as it is clean, and can wait for response from server. This helps in batch processing multiple forms. There is no fiddling around with DOM elements or adding delays that may fail due to runtime issues like sudden drop in internet speed.

My question however is, how do I create session if the website requires me to login? I did lookup documentation but couldn't find session options:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

I am open to suggestions if I can write my own program in VSCode using Node.js, JQuery, javascript etc, that loads json file as data and something that I can post on GitHub/GitLab for others to use as well. I know VBA method of doing it, but it relies on DOM elements to mimic user interaction. There is another program `mini mouse macro` that has a great reputation, but its an exe and mimics user interaction of clicks and delays. I want to see code that I am running.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your goal from `My question however is, how do I create session if the website requires me to login?`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? By the way, in your question, Google Apps Script is shown. From this, you want to achieve your goal using Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Tanaike, my goal is very similar to the original question in the post I have linked above. I want to log into a web site and from there I need to fill up a form multiple times. This form allows me to add record on to the web site in my account. Doing this manually is time consuming when records are in hundreds, hence automation. Note: the site does not provide proper API functionality so I have to rely on some sort of customisation. I found Google App Script as an option, but I am open for other solution if easier to implement.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, when the API can be used for submitting the form, I would like to propose to use it. But, if such API cannot be used, it is required to test the login using Google Apps Script because I cannot know the specification of the login to the site you want to use. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.